# Python 1 and l characters look the same

Tags: python, fonts, python-idle

When using python IDLE from [Python website](https://www.python.org/) I found an annoying problem: characters one  `1`  and lower L  `l`  look the same.
Is there a quick and practical way to solve this problem without making the whole text look much different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is!

IDLE uses `Courier New` as default font.
If you go to `Options > Configure IDLE > Fonts/Tabs` and change the `Font Face:` to `Consolas`, those characters become distinguishable but you keep the average look of the text!
(this is the font used on Windows' Text Notebook).